# Set the minimum IDF_VER required by my project

Tags: cmake, build, esp32, esp-idf

I want to make sure all users building my ESP-IDF project in eclipse are forced/warned to install a minimum version of the ESP-IDF.

I have done a fairly extensive search but was unable to find a solution to implement that. I guess I could do it in code, but I was hoping to implement that in the preprocessor/cmake when I build the project.

Something like:
`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)`

My alternative would probably be using `static_assert` ? But I was hoping to use a built-in function like above.

Comment: In the CMake code of your project you could check value of the `IDF_VER` variable or its parts (`IDF_VERSION_MAJOR`, `IDF_VERSION_MINOR`, `IDF_VERSION_PATCH`). In case of insufficient version you could terminate configuration with `message(FATAL_ERROR <...>)` command. These variables are descrbed in the [documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/build-system.html#build-project-variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [ESP-IDF Component Manager](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-component-manager.html) which allows you to create a manifest file containing detailed specification of all components used in the project, including the ESP IDF itself. I must admit, the [documentation for manifest file](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/idf-component-manager/en/latest/reference/manifest_file.html) is not very good, but have a look at a few examples from the [component manager](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/62ee4135e033cc85eb0d7572e5b5d147bcb4349e/examples/build_system/cmake/component_manager/main/idf_component.yml) or [mDNS project](https://github.com/espressif/esp-protocols/blob/master/components/mdns/examples/query_advertise/main/idf_component.yml) and it becomes clearer.

E.g. this manifest `main/idf_component.yml` requires ESP IDF v5.0 or higher, and component from [Espressif's component registry](https://components.espressif.com/) called "mdns" with version 1.1.0 (exactly):

```
dependencies:
  espressif/mdns: "==1.1.0"
  idf:
    version: ">=5.0"
```

It's not foolproof, obviously, but it's built into the idf.py tool. So running `idf.py build` just does all the magic for you.